# Symfony fosrestbundle optional parameter in route

Tags: api, symfony, fosrestbundle

I have an api rest and i try to give an optional paramter in my route like this :

```
/**
 * @Rest\View
 * @Rest\Get("/dossier/{idDossier}", requirements={"idDossier" = "\d+"}, defaults={"idDossier" = null})
 * @ApiDoc(
 *  description="...",
 *  parameters={
 *      {"name"="idDossier", "dataType"="integer", "required"=false, "description"="Folder Id"}
 *  }
 * )
 */

public function getDossierAction($idDossier = null, Request $request){
```

But i have an error :

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Rest\View" in method ...\Controller\DossierAPIController::getDossierAction() was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

Comment: check you have this statement `use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;`

Comment: thanks that work, but i have a new error, i have answered to post mdma

Comment: the apidoc from nelmio? check this statement also `use Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Annotation\ApiDoc;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not importing that annotation class. Put something like this after the namespace declaration:

```
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
```

so you can use it like what you have:

```
@Rest\View()
```

Comment: Thanks its ok !
After this i have the same with "APIDoc", so i do the the same : 
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as ApiDoc;
I can call two times the annotations as apidoc, and as rest ?

And now, i have an error : getDossierAction() does not exist.
My function is : public function getDossierAction($idDossier, Request $request){...
So why don't exist ?

Comment: its ok, i don't need "apidoc", all work fine with : /**
     * @Rest\View
     * @Rest\Get("/dossier/{idDossier}", requirements={"idDossier" = "\d+"}, defaults={"idDossier" = null})
     */

Thank you again :)